# Can categorical variables be treated as count data?

Tags: categorical-data, poisson-distribution, count-data

In a questionnaire study, I asked for the frequency of certain behaviors using a 5-point scale.　Originally, I planned to treat it as categorical, however, distribution of the answers (N=1000) turns out to be more like zero-inflated Poisson. In fact, data fit well with zero-inflated Poisson regression model. Would it be justifiable to treat categorical data as counts in such case?

It seems like the data could be seen as count information, as I asked number of behaviors (anchor of the 5-point scale was as follows: 0=never, 1=less than once a week, 2= two to three times a week, 3=almost every day, 4=everyday).

Thank you very much for your insights!

Comment: What is it that you want to do with this variable? Is it intended as an explanatory variable or a response variable? What are your goals in this study?

Answer (score 2):

For a variable that was simply ordinal, it *could* be done; the better question is whether it should. I see several problems, starting with what is probably the most critical:

1) ordered categories are ordinal, not interval nor ratio (while the Poisson is for count data which is ratio)

2) the Poisson has non-zero probability of exceeding 5, while your variable doesn't.

However, your data consist of discretized frequencies (and that's not actually a count). You might be able to use the actual definitions of your categories to get intervals of frequencies per week, though the vagueness of category 3 is a problem; if you can argue that category 3 actually covers the territory between "more than 3 times per week but less than 7 times per week" then this variable could be handled essentially as what's effectively a set of interval-censored categories.

As such I generally still wouldn't use a Poisson model (because the content of the intervals that the categories contain don't correspond to the category labels - the weekly frequency covered by "4" isn't four times as often as the weekly frequency covered by "1", for example), but I *might* use something that attempted to use more of the information than treating it as a purely ordered-categorical variable.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can of course do this *if* the variables are ordered.

The question is what your result will be useful, but that is hard to predict...

In your case, you make the differences 1-0 (less than once a week vs. never ever) the *same* as 4-3 (almost every day vs. every day). I'm not convinced that this is the same *difference*...

This problem is quite well known in the context of [Likert items](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale). I believe the modern evaluation of such data does not use the numerical values, even when the users were asked to "rate on a scale of 1 to 5" etc. because there is a lot of **psychological bias** in the way you choose options (prefer extremes, central tendencies, etc.) most likely, this also applies to your data. E.g. when would a user say "every day" and not "almost every day"?
After such correction, you may end up with only three values: 0 and 1 = low, 2 = medium, 3 and 4 = high. And even though these are still ordered, it may yield better results to treat these as categories.